# C++ - member function and array of objects

Tags: c++, function, class, member-functions

When I have a class and create one object, it's simple to call a member function. It's something like this:

```
class Foo
{
    ...
public:
    void function();
}

void Foo::function()
{
    ...
}

int main()
{
    Foo f1;
    f1.function();
}
```

But how should I call a member function when I'm going to create an array of objects?

```
class Foo
{
    ...
public:
    void function();
}

void Foo::function()
{
    ...
}

int main()
{
    Foo *f1;
    ???
}
```

Comment: Where is the array? `f1` is a pointer, not an array.

Comment: `f1->function()` if it's a pointer to a single object, or `f1[index].function()` if it's a pointer to an array of objects.

Comment: Nothing different than what you would normally do. Just say Foo *f1 = new Foo[15]; and call their methods.

Answer (score 0):

Object:

```
A a;
a.foo()
```

Pointer:

```
A *a;
a->foo();
```

Table/"Array":

```
A a[10];
a[0].foo()
```

Those are really basics available in every free c++ course.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks, that's what I meant. And what if I have a pointer to pointer (A **a) instead of just a pointer?

Comment: @Rqw9Pl8gDm, you de-reference once more. I suggest you get back to basics. This is material covered in any good c++ book.

Comment: for example `(*a)->foo()`. But also other ways depending on situation. e.g. `a[0][0].foo()`. You really have to do some c++ curse before going deeper. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int main()
{
    Foo arrayOfFoo[5];
    arrayOfFoo[0].function();
}
```

This creates 5 objects of type *Foo* in an array called *arrayOfFoo*
Then it performs the method *function()* on the object at array index 0 in the array *arrayOfFoo*.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create an array of objects . You can do so by `Foo f1[100];` statement in `main`.

I chose the random number 100, you can choose any. Also , to access the member function you have to use the dot operator. For e.g.

```
f1[1].function()
```